# Getting error : Unexpected exception occurred: templates/email.txt in django email

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

When i am trying to send HTML email, i am getting error :  `Unexpected exception occurred: templates/email.txt`,  can anyone please help me why i am getting this error ? here i have attached my whole code.

email.txt

```
Click <a href="">here</a> to signup for the company
```

email.html

```
Click <a href="">here</a> to signup for the company
```

views.py

class Inviteuser(APIView):

```
def post(self, request):

    try:
        required_params = ['user_id', 'user_email']
        data = request.data
        if all(key in data for key in required_params):
            user_id = data['user_id']
            user_email = data['user_email']

            inviteuser_object = InviteUser()
            inviteuser_object.user_id = user_id
            inviteuser_object.email = user_email
            inviteuser_object.save()



            # Send Email
            subject = 'Invited to Trial Risk'
            msg_plain = render_to_string('templates/email.txt', {'user_id': user_id})
            msg_html = render_to_string('templates/email.html', {'user_id': user_id})
            send_mail(
                'Invited to Trial Risk',
                msg_plain,
                '****@gmail.com',
                [user_email],
                html_message=msg_html,
            )

            return Response({"success": True, "status": "Success"},
                            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        else:
            return Response(
                {"success": False, "error": "Required param(s) missing, Please include and retry again"},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    except Exception as exp:
        print("Unexpected exception occurred: " + str(exp))
        return Response({"success": False, "error": "Unexpected error occurred, please report this to Admin"},
                        status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Comment: Could you provide some additional information like the full traceback and the complete view? Taking your code provided currently I could not reproduce the error

Comment: i have updated my code

Comment: With the line `except Exception as exp:` you are catching ALL exception and - instead of the full traceback - print a generic one-liner. This is not a good idea. Try removing the try / catch block and see what the traceback tells you